# Why does a directory appear when viewing the home folder but not when I use the command line in Linux?

Tags: find, ubuntu-12.04, ls

It's an odd problem in that when I browse the home folder I see the directory 'Jquery' however when I use the command line nothing appears. I have used the commands `ls | less`, `find . -iname jQuery`, etc however no result is returned.

1. Why does this occur?
2. How can I view it using the command line?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Maybe the folder is hidden? Try `ls -la`

Comment: You mention `Jquery` and `jQuery`, these are different names, case matters.

Comment: @Red - Unless you use `-iname` with `find`, which he did. @PeanutsMonkey - why don't you right click on that folder and see its properties (type, location etc)... maybe there's something special about it.

Comment: @gentlesea - That's very odd indeed. It does now appear however when I attempt to access it via `cd jQuery`, it returns a message saying there is no such file or directory. This raises a few questions. 1) What attributes do I need to look at when looking at hidden directories via the command line 2) How do I unhide it? 3) Why can I access the hidden directory? 4)Lastly why does the `find` command not locate it?